# How to delete Ethernet profiles?(picture link attachment)

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I have "Ethernet" and "Ethernet 3" profiles as shown below and I want to delete them. I'm also confused there is something written just below their name which are "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller" and "TAP-Windows Adapter V9". They sound like system drivers so if I delete those profiles I might lose those drivers too and then I may not use my USB modem further . Why with different Ethernet profile there is different driver? Is it safe to delete it and if yes then how to delete it?

[image: Network Connections]

On right click, delete option is grey field, see here

[image: Right click menu]

Comment: Should be as simple as right clicking on the adapter and hitting the Delete key.

Comment: Delete option is grey field I don't know why.

Comment: What is the name of the second adapter? It looks like it's another physical/virtual adapter so that may be why you can't delete it. Depending what it is, to remove it you may have to go into device manager and delete or disable the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Your post title asks how to delete, but your questions asks what are they/what is the difference **AND** How to delete?  SO typically limits to **ONE** question per post as the answer can vary greatly if you ask multiple questions.

To Delete -->
you should be able to right click on it, and choose delete from the list.

What are they -->

The Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller is just the "name" of the actual LAN card.

Instances when I have seen "TAP Windows Adapter" is when using a VPN software, or in rare instances when you have allowed internet access to a Virtual Machine.

**IF** you are not using a VPN of sorts, nor a Virtual Machine you should be safe to remove the "TAP" device listed, however I would keep the "Realtek" device listed.

**EDIT**
I have also seen multiple instances of the same device listed such as "Realtek" and "Realtek1" when you have connected a LAN cable, and selected this is a "Home" network, then next time you plug in a LAN cable you select this is a "Public" network.

Comment: On right click DELETE option is grey field.